# fit the plot to the entire page in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I use PGFPlots to create graphs and export them into my keynote slides. I always have to trim the sides of the exported pdf file. Attached is an example of such a graph.[image] I wonder if there is a way to automatically fit the plot into the whole page in the pdf file?

Here is the code that produces the graph

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}%fitting functions
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,patterns,pgfplots.fillbetween}

\pagestyle{empty}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\LARGE},
            tick label style={font=\LARGE}}

\pgfplotsset{error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both, x explicit,
    y dir=both, y explicit,
    }

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enable tick line clipping=false, % makes all ticks same width
    axis line style=semithick,
    width=14cm,
    height=7cm,
    x tick style={black,semithick},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={$L$ [mm]},
    xmin=0,xmax=100,
    xtick={0,20,...,100},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    xtick align=outside,
    y tick style={black,semithick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={$F$ [N]},
    ymin=-0.05,ymax=0.2,
    ytick={-0.05,0,...,0.25},
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
]
    \addplot [only marks,mark=*,mark options={scale=0.5,red,fill=white}] file {LDPE_PETG_2.txt};

    \addplot [only marks,mark=*,mark options={scale=0.5,blue,fill=white}] file {LDPE-DOTO_PETG_2.txt};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try `\pgfplotsset{width=\textwidth,height=\textheight}`? Or just replace `width=14cm,
    height=7cm,` by `width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,`

Comment: It's not exactly what you're looking for, but you could add this in the preamble.
```
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm,paperheight=10cm]{geometry}
```

Comment: If you are exporting the plots, why not use standalone class?  Don't use figure, and if you need a caption use` \captionof{figure}{...}` (caption or capt-of packages).

Comment: Thank you @John Kormylo, `documenstcalss{standalone}` does the job. Moreover, I can perfectly fit it to the page and still use the `width=xcm` and `height=ycm` to adjust the plot size.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use TikZ's `external` ([tag:tikz-external]) library to export your plots.